# KeyError in city name

Tags: django, openweathermap

I have made an small weather web app in django & it is working properly but 
when a wrong city name is entered it start showing KeyError page.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
import requests

#search page
def search(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

#forecast result page
def forecast(request):
    c = request.POST['city']
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid=7fee53226a6fbc936e0308a3f4941aaa&units=metric'.format(c)
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    weather = {
        'description': data['weather'][0]['description'],
        'icon': data['weather'][0]['icon'],
        'city': c.title(),
        'temperature': data['main']['temp']
            }
    print(r)
    return render(request, 'weather.html', {'weather': weather})
```

On entering wrong city name it is giving KeyError,So I want that instead of giving KeyError django will redirect it to my homepage i.e index.html with an error message below it.

Answer (score 1):

The API will tell you if the city name is not valid.

```
r = requests.get(url)
if r.status_code == 404:
    messages.add_message('City not found')
    return redirect('home')
data = r.json()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please do *not* construct the querysetring yourself: *querystrings* can not include a lot of characters. You can use Django's `QueryDict` for that, like:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
qd.update(q=c, appid='7fee53226a6fbc936e0308a3f4941aaa', units='metric')
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?{}'.format(qd.urlencode())
```

For cities like `'New York'`, it will encode this as:

```
>>> qd.urlencode()
'q=New+York&appid=7fee53226a6fbc936e0308a3f4941aaa&units=metric'
```

so it replaces the space with a `+`.

Furthermore you can use `try`-`except` here to redirect to a different page, like:

```
from django.http import QueryDict
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def forecast(request):
    try:
        city = request.POST['city']
    except:
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
    qd.update(q=city, appid='7fee53226a6fbc936e0308a3f4941aaa', units='metric')
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?{}'.format(qd.urlencode())
    try:
        data = r.json()
        weather = {
            'description': data['weather'][0]['description'],
            'icon': data['weather'][0]['icon'],
            'city': c.title(),
            'temperature': data['main']['temp']
        }
    except KeyError:
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    return render(request, 'weather.html', {'weather': weather})
```

You can use the [*Django Messages Framework* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) to show messages to a user.